# Is it always true that $(A_1\cap A_2)\times(B_1\cap B_2)=(A_1\times B_1)\cap (A_2\times B_2)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it always true that
$$(A_1\cap A_2)\times(B_1\cap B_2)=(A_1\times B_1)\cap (A_2\times B_2)\qquad ?$$
I believe it is, but I wanted to make sure than I am on the right path. I proved containment for both sides by picking arbitrary elements $(a,b)$ to be in the LHS, and I have shown that they are in the RHS, and vice-versa. is this correct to solve a problem like this?

Comment: yes, if that's what you did it is correct.

Comment: You can also prove this by showing that the statement of specification upon each set is logically equivalent to the other.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered already in the comments, so I thought I'd make a community wiki answer.  Yes, to show that two sets $x$ and $y$ are equal it is enough to show that $x \subseteq y$ and $y \subseteq x$.  This follows from the Axiom of Extensionality: sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements.